# Any quotient representation of completely reducible is completely reducible.

Tags: representation-theory, invariant-theory

Prove that every quotient representation of a completely reducible representation is completely reducible.

Could anyone give me a hint for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint :** if $M$ is completely reducible, $N$ is a subrepresentation, and $K$ a subrepresentation of $M/N$, we wish to find a subrepresentation $S$ of $M/N$ such that $K\oplus S = M/N$.

If $\pi: M\to M/N$ is the projection map, what can you say about $\pi^{-1}(K)$ ? What does the hypothesis on $M$ tell us ?

Comment: How you will show that every invariant subspace has an invariant complement ?

Comment: For the first question I do not know the answer .... For the second question the hypothesis tell us that every invariant subspace has an invariant complement .... but then what Max ?

Comment: $\pi^{-1}(K)$ is an invariant subspace, can you see why ?

Comment: No I can not Max

Comment: Can you recall the definition of $\pi^{-1}(K)$ ?

Comment: The set of all points in whose images are in K

Comment: All points in M

Comment: Ok, can you now take such a point $x$, apply $g$ to it, and see if its image is still in $K$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by apply g to it .... what is g .... How can I apply it Max ?

Comment: You were talking about a representation... ?